# AWS AppSync GraphQL - How to use PK/SK query instead of scanning whole dynamoDB table for graphql list APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

My DynamoDB table data schema:

```
PartitionKey: "PK" -> String
SortKey: "SK" -> Number (timestamp)
Attribute: "Summary" -> JsonMap
```

My main usecase is that I have a "PK" and the range of "SK", which is the target time range, and query DDB to get a list of "Summaries". This data design is good for DDB APIs.

Now, I want to use AppSync to create a GraphQL API for this DynamoDB for a Amplify app. So I create a GraphQL schema like this:

```
type DataSummary {
    PK: String!
    SK: Float!
    Summary: AWSJSON
}
```

GraphQL automatically creates 2 query APIs for me: `getDataSummary` and `listDataSummary`. What supperises me is, when I do list API, I can use filter to define the query as:

```
query listDataSummaries {
  listDataSummaries(filter: {PK: {eq: "##Some key string##}"}, SK: {gt: ##Some timestamp##}}) {
    items {
      PK
      SK
      Summary
    }
  }
}
```

But, the return value is "null" because of paginating, which means GraphQL is doing a table scan to gather all items in the table and then does a filter based on my request. This is against my table design because it requires significantly more RCUs than a normal DDB API call for the same result.
So, what did I miss? How can I "ask" GraphQL to do a DDB query instead of a scan for PK/SK list operation?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the direction to investigate:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/configuring-resolvers.html

Comment: Did you found the solution for this question in the docs?